# How to save Radare2 Analysis?

Tags: radare2

How do I save a radare2 session after I did "aa"?

I know there is a command for saving a project, but this isn't working out for some reason (Ps PROJECTNAME). So I am looking for a way to save my analysis progress and if possible retain renamed variables.

It currently doesn't work because if I open it again another time it won't load the renamed variables and I can't do stuff like "ood" which is the way to reopen the binary as far as I'm concerned. But there are no errors.

After invoking radare2 with `r2 -d calc` I run `aa` and then `Ps calc_project`. After that I close the terminal and open up a new one. Then I start with `r2 -d calc` again and follow it with `Po calc_project`. Now, there are many errors which appear to be the same over and over again:

```
fcn_recurse failed
Cannot add basic block", that message 50 times or more.
```

Version information:

```
radare2 version: 
radare2 3.1.0-git 20049 @ linux-x86-64 git.3.0.1-214-g5759f21
commit: 5759f217c941478ef265bf9a6ba5e23cd646661a
```

Comment: Why Ps doesn’t work? Any error?

Comment: please edit your question and state how you actually do the `Ps`. I'm doing it and see no obvious issues - also state what version of r2 you are using.

Comment: Hey unicorn123, going by the assumption that you are the same individual as @q7v6rhgfzc8tnj3d you can request your accounts [to be merged](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). If you don't want or need that, it's okay as well. This is also the likely reason you could not comment on your own question then.

Comment: In recent times the r2 project system has been broken. Try updating or opening an issue